# cdata-section-elements not working

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, saxon

I am trying to set a password in an xml file generated via XSLT (using Saxon-HE v9.7.0.14), by setting a global parameter.

The password can contain any characters so it needs to be put in a `CDATA` section.

I am trying to achieve this by setting the `cdata-section-elements` attribute of my xslt's `xsl:output` element to include the name of the password element:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="password"/>
```

This is not working. I have included example code, input, xslt, current output and desired output below.

**What do I need to change to get the password inside a `CDATA` section?**

**Program:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Saxon.Api;

namespace XsltTest {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var xslt = new FileInfo(@"transform.xslt");
            var input = new FileInfo(@"input.xml");
            var output = new FileInfo(@"output.xml");
            var processor = new Processor();
            var compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
            var executable = compiler.Compile(new Uri(xslt.FullName));
            var transformer = executable.Load();
            var destination = new DomDestination();
            using (var inputStream = input.OpenRead()) {               
                transformer.SetInputStream(inputStream, new Uri(Path.GetTempPath()));
                transformer.SetParameter(
                    new QName("password"),
                    new XdmAtomicValue("secret"));
                transformer.Run(destination);
            }
            destination.XmlDocument.Save(output.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

**Transform.xslt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="password"/>
  <xsl:param name="password" />
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <bar>
      <username>
        <xsl:value-of select="//username"/>
      </username>
      <password>
        <xsl:value-of select="$password"/>
      </password>
    </bar>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<foo>
  <username>john</username>
</foo>
```

**Output.xml:**

```
<bar>
  <username>john</username>
  <password>secret</password>
</bar>
```

The password is not put inside a `CDATA` section.

**Desired result:**

```
<bar>
  <username>john</username>
  <password><![CDATA[secret]]></password>
</bar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options on `xsl:output` affect the actions of the serializer, and if the output is not serialized, they have no effect. You are writing to a DomDestination rather than to a Serializer (and then serializing the DOM using DOM methods, which know nothing about the XSLT xsl:output declaration).

In any case your premise is wrong: "The password can contain any characters so it needs to be put in a CDATA section." Without cdata-section-elements, special characters will be serialized using entity references such as `&lt;` and `&amp;`, which should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks. I've now used `Serializer` instead of `DomDestination` and it is working. Thanks also for the comment regarding entity encoding without CDATA. I'm actually replacing a system that already sends XML messages with the password in CDATA, and the team before me said they had problems before using CDATA. We don't have control over the external system reading the messages, so I assumed the problem was not handling the XML properly on their end, and I know it works when using CDATA.

Comment: Generating XML for people who parse it incompetently is only marginally less of a hassle than reading (so-called) XML created by people who generate it incompetently - sadly there is a lot of incompetence in our profession.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it appears to be working correctly.

The input line

```
xsltproc --stringparam password "1>2Ä-34" Transform.xslt Input.xml
```

returns the desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bar>
  <username>john</username>
  <password><![CDATA[1>2Ä-34]]></password>
</bar>
```

Did you miss the input of the `password` parameter to the XSLT processor to feed the `<xsl:param name="password" />`?

Comment: I'm not using xsltproc. I'm using Saxon in a C# application as per the example program.

Comment: Yes. I knew. But it is similar: pass the string-parameter "password" with its value to the XSLT. It should work like I described in my answer. The empty `<xsl:param name="password" />` at the `xsl:stylesheet` level is determined for purposes like that.

Answer (score 0):

[Michael Kay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42020913/177018) explained the solution, which was that the `cdata-section-elements` attribute is only applicable when writing to a `Serializer` not a `DomDestination`.

Here's the C# code for doing that:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var xslt = new FileInfo(@"transform.xslt");
    var input = new FileInfo(@"input.xml");
    var output = new FileInfo(@"output.xml");
    var processor = new Processor();
    var compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
    var executable = compiler.Compile(new Uri(xslt.FullName));
    var transformer = executable.Load();
    var serializer = new Serializer();
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(output.FullName))
    using (var inputStream = input.OpenRead()) {
        serializer.SetOutputWriter(writer);
        transformer.SetInputStream(inputStream, new Uri(Path.GetTempPath()));
        transformer.SetParameter(
            new QName("password"),
            new XdmAtomicValue("secret"));
        transformer.Run(serializer);
    }
```