# Why am I getting multiple cdata in xml tag when get cdata element with emoji

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon, xerces

I've been googling around for hours (days) now without finding why I have this issue, let me explain this to you.

## Summary

I want to transform an xml, more specificaly, get a tag value which is a cdata with an emoji in it. But, after the transformation, I got this `<cdata-given-xml-value><![CDATA[A - ]]><![CDATA[ - B]]></cdata-given-xml-value>` instead of this `<cdata-given-xml-value>A -  - B</cdata-given-xml-value>`

All the details here after :

## input xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d>
    <t><![CDATA[A -  - B]]></t>
</d>
```

## input xsl :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output
        method="xml"
        encoding="utf-8"
        indent="yes"
        cdata-section-elements="cdata-given-xml-value"
    />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="xml-value" select="/d/t/text()" />
        <d>
            <cdata-given-xml-value><xsl:copy-of select="$xml-value" /></cdata-given-xml-value>
            <given-xml-value><xsl:value-of select="$xml-value" /></given-xml-value>
        </d>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## expected :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d>
    <cdata-given-xml-value><![CDATA[A -  - B]]></cdata-given-xml-value>
    <given-xml-value>A - &#128176; - B</given-xml-value>
</d>
```

## actual :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d>
  <cdata-given-xml-value><![CDATA[A - ]]><![CDATA[ - B]]></cdata-given-xml-value>
  <given-xml-value>A - &#128176; - B</given-xml-value>
</d>
```

## java :

This implementation is the one available in `rt.jar`

```java
public void Xslt(Document document, File xsl, String encoding, Writer writer, String... args) throws TransformerException {
    // Set system property here for tests purpose
    System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl");

    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new 
    StreamSource(xsl));
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, true);
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(writer));
}
```

I tried with `saxon-he` too, but it does not permit the use of integrated extension functions (calls to java methods) and I need this functionnality.

`xalan-2.7.2.jar` seems to have the same issue.

Let me know if you need more data ;-)

Comment: Check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017856/cdata-section-elements-not-working

Comment: Does Saxon HE give you at least the result for your test case that you want? Also, while HE does not allow reflexive extensions its extension mechanism to *support* calling Java methods is called *integrated extension functions*, I think (https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/extensibility/integratedfunctions/)

Comment: There are also various bugs filed on Xalan related to astral Unicode characters I think, some with patches. So perhaps building your own update or checking whether someone else has done it and reusing will sort this. I am kind of sure we had a question here a while ago with someone pointing to a prerelease/patched version related to Unicode problems but I am afraid I fail to find it with a search now.

Comment: @MartinHonnen yes, I think I already read something about this. the patch and a pull request were made in xalan repository and are available in a corresponding issue, but the project is dead... so no one merge it yet. I'm not a fan of customs implementations by the way, but on a dead project, why not. 
Have you any other libs to recommand instead of Xalan ans Saxon HE ? 
Big thank you for your time :)
Edit: here is the issue : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2617

Comment: I wouldn't recommend moving to the 10 years old Saxon 9.1 Basic but it is still available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-B/9.1.0.8/ and should run XSLT 2 while supporting reflexive extension functions. If I remember it right, it was the last open-source release of Saxon to do that before restructuring the software into the commercial PE and EE packages still supporting reflexive extension functions and the open-source HE package supporting (only) integrated extension functions.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a very old, 1.0 processor from `rt.jar`, is my guess. Its serializer is confused by characters not in the BMP?

I did a quick experiment and Saxon HE does what you want.

You can run Java functions from Saxon HE, but you have to work a little harder to get them configured. If you don't have too many, and you don't need the ability to call arbitrary Java functions, that might be a way forward.

You can find examples of configuring Saxon HE to run Java extension functions in, for example, https://github.com/docbook/xslTNG/

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer, actually my company maintain hundreds of xsl and it is not an option for us to reconfigure all of them for each clients. That's why i'm looking for something "similiar" at what we already have. However, if we have no choice... ^^